# Error #1010 In AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm trying to make a water system where the water particles collide with each other, but I keep getting this error.

```
[object water]
TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.
at science_fla::MainTimeline/feed()
```

Here is the code:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import com.coreyoneil.collision.CollisionList;
//etc

stop();

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,feed);

function feed(event:MouseEvent)
{
    var wat:water = new water(event.target.mouseX,event.target.mouseY);

    MovieClip(root).addChild(wat);
    particles.push(wat);

    for(var i = 0; i < particles.length;i++)
    {
        if (particles[i]!=wat)
        {
            trace(particles[i]);
            wat.myCollision.addItem(particles[i]);
        }

        particles.myCollision.addItem(wat);
    }
}
```

Thanks for all of your help. If you need more code, just ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say the issue is this line:

```
particles.myCollision.addItem(wat);
```

`particles` is an array, and arrays don't have the property `myCollision`.

Did you mean `particles[i].myCollision`?

Comment: haha thanks for the hoisting tip, I swear it didn't always employ that, and just beat me to the that conclusion, upvoted.

Comment: @Montycarlo Sure - yeah AS2, AS3 and JavaScript all use hoisting :)

Comment: Also he misses `else` before that statement, otherwise `wat` will collide with `wat`. EDIT: oops that statement should be inside an `if`, so that each particle will have all the other particles in collision list.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are accessing the variable which is not defined earlier. Actually your question is difficult to understand. Please let me know more code and which line it's got error. Or try that water variable not on certain function make it to global. and try . And also let me know what that water variables contains it has movieclip or any thing.?

Comment: I want to downvote this so bad but I have nice rounded reputation at the moment.

Comment: I could n't get you Mr marty.